# Stem comparsion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, nlp, stemming

I'm writing a program that makes word declension for Polish language. In this language stems can vary in some cases (because of palatalization or mobile/fleeting e and other effects).

For example, we have word "karzeł" and it is basic dictionary form of word. It's stem is also 'karzeł'. But genitive form of this word is "karła" and stem is "karł". We can see here that 'e' dissapeared and 'rz' changes to 'r'.

Another example:
'uzda' -> stem 'uzd'
'uździe' -> stem 'uździ'
Alternation: 'zd' -> 'ździ'

I'd like to store in dictionary only basic form of stem ('karzeł' and 'uzd') and when I'll put in my program stem 'karł' or 'uździ' it will find proper basic stems. Alternations takes place only at the end of stem and contains maximum 4 letters of it.

Is there any algorithms that could do that? Levensthein distance treats all letters equally so if I type word 'barzeł' then the distance to stem 'karzeł' will be less than to stem 'karł'.

I thought also about neural networks but I'm not sure how to encode words (give each stem variation different id?).

Another idea is to write algorith which makes something like reversed alternation and creates set of possible stems and try to find them in dictionary.

I would like to highlight that I only want store basic form of stem and everything else makes on the fly.

Comment: levenshtein distance can be customized so as to give more weight to some letters or sequence of letters.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I remember seeing a number of projects on Polish morphology around. So I would look at them first, before starting one of your own.

Regarding Levenshtein, as Pierre correctly noted in the comment, the distance function can be customized. And it should be. Let me put it this way: think of Levenshtein not as an algorithm of and in itself, but as a solution to a specific error model. First he suggests a model which says that when you are typing a word every letter can be either dropped or replaced by another one due to some random process (fingers not pressing the right keys). Then, his algorithm is just a generator of maximum likelihood solutions under this model. The more errors you allow, the smaller is the probability of this sequence of errors actually happening, the bigger is the score.

You (implicitly) state a very different hypothesis, though. That Polish stems may have certain flexibility at the end (some linguistic process that you do not fully understand within this framework). Then, when you strip your suffix (or something that looks like one), there are three options: 
1) there is a chance that what you have here is just a different form of a stem you have stored in your dictionary, or 
2) it is a completely different stem, or 
3) you've stripped your suffix improperly and what you have is not stem at all. 
You can heuristically estimate these probabilities by looking at how many letters in the beginning of the supposed stem match some dictionary entries, for example (how to find these entries is a related but different question). And then you can pick the guess that is the most plausible according to your metric/heuristic.

Now, note that you can use any algorithm to find the candidates in the dictionary. Including the Levenshtein algorithm - as long as you are reasonably sure that the right ones will be picked up. But obviously you are better off writing your own dictionary search algorithm that follows your own metric or emulates it. For example, by giving the biggest/prohibitive cost to the change of letters in the beginning of the word and reducing it as you go towards the end.